# How to get a notification when user deletes a file?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to get a notification (like a state with "delete" action and file id) when the user deletes a file of my app on drive?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

There is no notification right now, but if you look at the [Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list) for an account, there will be an entry with `deleted` field set to `true` with the File ID for the deleted file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be great if a "delete" url could be added to the drive sdk some day to be able to receive push notifications on delete. This would allow me to track all deletions without polling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a knowleges in Google-drive-sdk, but I have already create a similar function in php:

With a CRON ( php script running in background task) I list files in my folder, and I compare with a database ( I add a filename, size file, in database when user add file) , if file exist in database, and not exist in my list, user delete this file and I want send a notification...

until a person expert on "Google-drive" you find a solution, I hope mine will come in handy.